# Wordpress admin page redirects

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to setup my wordpress site on my local machine. I copied the wordpress site from aws and copied data into mysql. 
I'm running MAMP on my machine.I'm able to access my site when i visit http://localhost:8888.

But when I want to visit the admin page i get redirected to the original website

```
➜  htdocs  http http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 13 Apr 2016 13:23:06 GMT
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Location: http://mywebsite.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 PHP/5.5.26 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8zg DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.22.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.26
```

Any idea why i'm seeing redirects ?

Comment: Looks like a plugin is breaking the installation. Try deleting the plugin `gravity-slider-fields`

Comment: probably your  php version 5.6, strict standards

Comment: Try to compare PHP / Wordpress versions of your environnements....

Comment: @JamesPaterson I disabled the slider plugin and now i'm seeing a new issue, where i see a redirect.

Comment: You said you moved your site from AWS : have you changed the wp-config file accordingly ? and i am sure there will be still some old domain reference in the db as well, and you might also want to check your .htaccess file.